# go coverage sometimes fails to write file

Tags: go

Our Jenkins build has a line like

```
go test -p=4 -count=1 -timeout=3m -v -coverprofile=coverage.out ./...
```

Usually this is fine but sometimes it fails with an error like

```
vet: $WORK/b1704/cache.cover.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
```

The build slave machine has about 5 GB available at the start of the build, and it didn't appear to drop below 4GB during the build, although it's possible I missed  transient spike in usage.

This is the only command executing at the time, there is no parallelisation in the build script, only what is done by `go test -p` itself.

Any ideas what could cause an intermittent failure like that?

go version go1.14 linux/arm64

Comment: That means it's trying to read a 0-byte file. `cache.cover.go` is apparently empty. As for why it's intermittent, there's no way of saying based on the information you've provided. Whatever creates/copies that file is apparently failing in some way.

Comment: The file is created by the go tools. I think it's the coverage tool. And yes it's obviously failing sometimes. Hence the question.

Comment: That's surprising to me. Maybe you're right, but I see no mention of that file anywhere in any Go tool source, nor on Google.

Comment: looks like go vet is being run as part of your build pipeline. And looks like it is running in parallel and some times go vet hits the coverage.out file created by the coverage tool. You may have to exclude that file from your go vet?